# How to activate conda environment with space in its name?

Tags: python, conda, virtual-environment

Environment name is with space in-between:

```
    flask app
```

Location:

```
    E:\&$&$&$&$&$&\miniconda\envs\flask app
```

I tried activating the environment with below commands:

```
activate flask app
activate -p E:\&$&$&$&$&$&\miniconda\envs\flask app
```

I did not go through.

Please help if someone know about this trick.

Comment: what's the output of `conda info --envs` ?

Comment: Have you tried using quotes: `"E:\thing\flask app"`?

Comment: @ForceBru Thank you.  " "  around the environment path worked.